# Can't remove disabled attribute from button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to make a button available only if the content of an input changed this way:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input[name="tesztinput1"]').keyup(function(){
          alert('Content has been changed');
          if ($(this).val())
          {
            $('input[name="tesztinput3"]').removeAttr('disabled');
          }
        })
});
```

And in the HTML:

```
<input name="tesztinput1" type="text"/>
<input name="tesztinput3" type="button" disabled="disabled" value="Click"/>
```

It properly works if the element which i want to remove disable attribute is a text input aswell but not working on buttons and submit elements. Any idea?

So this part of the code itself seems to be okay I tested every suggestion in the recent answer and no result. What else could block me from executing an action like this?

Comment: [Unable to reproduce](http://jsfiddle.net/j3BvF/).

Comment: It should work but preferred method is to use prop instead: `$('input[name="tesztinput3"]').prop('disabled',false);`

Comment: Your code *already works*.  If not, then there's something you else going on and you didn't include it in the question. Have you checked the browser console for errors?

Comment: Checked in Firebug, no errors

Answer (score 2):

Use [**.prop()**](http://api.jquery.com/prop/),

To disable

```
 $('input[name="tesztinput3"]').prop('disabled', true);
```

To enable

```
 $('input[name="tesztinput3"]').prop('disabled', false);
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/6u4sy/)

Also read [.prop() vs .attr()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr)

Answer (score 0):

Well, I didn't succeed in solving the problem but i found a workaround: I use readonly instead of disabled, because of something it works correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a "Input" rather than "Button":

```
$('input[name="tesztinput3"]').prop('disabled', false);
```

Just work in a "Input".